# How can I fill a text at the end of my arc?

Tags: html, canvas

I'm trying to place a text inside my semi circle, graph. I simplified the arc for you `context.arc(92.5, 92.5, 72.5, 3.141592653589793, 3.7699111843077517, false);` I want to place a value `2` at the end of arc, since the arc represents 20% of overall value.

So far I have tried is

```
context.translate(centerX, centerY);
context.save();
context.translate(x, y);
context.fillText('2', 0, 3);
context.restore();
```

I tried to find x and y interception point using  `(−ℎ)2+(−)2=2`. But I can't place the text at the end of arc. Can some one please help me to solve this? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to find the point where the arc ends:

```
let x = center.x + radius * Math.cos(endArc);
let y = center.y + radius * Math.sin(endArc);
```

In this case the center of the circle is in the point {x:92.5,y:92.5}, the radius is 72.5. and the end arc is 3.7699111843077517.

I hope this is what you were asking.

```js
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
let cw = canvas.width = 200;
let ch= canvas.height = 200;
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(92.5, 92.5, 72.5, 3.141592653589793, 3.7699111843077517, false);
ctx.stroke();
//find the point where the arc ends
let x = 92.5 + 72.5 * Math.cos(3.7699111843077517);
let y = 92.5 + 72.5 * Math.sin(3.7699111843077517);
// draw the text
ctx.font="12px Arial";  
ctx.textAlign="center";
ctx.textBaseline="bottom"; 
ctx.fillText("2",x,y);
```

```css
canvas{border:1px solid}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thank you. Thank you very much.